# Can I disable image resizing when using ImageGenerator?

Tags: keras

The resize step in the Keras image preprocessing function flow_from_dataframe is done before the self-defined preprocessing function. However, I want to resize the image after I finish all the pre-processing. How can I disable the resize? How should I set the target_size parameter?